# andcontinue()-method executed as a async operation

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, asynchronous, windows-phone-8.1

For windows phone 8.1 microsoft introduced some methods, which end with `AndContinue`. These methods suspend the app to execute and process user input. Afterwards they call a `Continue...`-method with a object containing the result of the operation.

A example would be `WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAndContinue`, which is used for OAuth.

Example code:

```
class Test : IWebAuthenticationContinuable
{
    private void StartAuth()
    {
        WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAndContinue(new Uri("http://example.org/token?someInformations"),
                new Uri("http://example.org/callback"), null, WebAuthenticationOptions.None);
    }

    private void ContinueWebAuthentication(WebAuthenticationBrokerContinuationEventArgs args)
    {
        WebAuthenticationResult result = args.WebAuthenticationResult;

        //Do something with the result
    }
}
```

In windows store apps the same is achived by using the `WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAsync`-emthod. This method is a simple async operation.

I'd like to write a `AuthenticateAsync`-method for windows phone using `AuthenticateAndContinue`. It must return a `Task<WebAuthenticationResult>`.

As a quite hacky approach, I thought about a `Task`, which is completed after the execution of `ContinueWebAuthentication`. If I await this task and set the result in some variable, I could access it in the async method and return it.

But I wasn't able to figure out how to implement this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `AndContinue` APIs are not asynchronous calls like the Windows Store `AuthenticateAsync` is. [From MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn631755.aspx):

> When you call an AndContinue method, your app is deactivated while the operation completes in order to conserve memory. On low-memory devices, your app might even be terminated.

So, when you call an `AndContinue` method, your app can be terminated. When your app is restored, you'll need some way of jumping back into your `async` method. There's nothing like this built-in AFAIK.

It is certainly possible to create a `Task<WebAuthenticationResult>` using `TaskCompletionSource<T>`, but it won't work in this case. The `AndContinue` method can terminate your app, and when your app resumes, it can complete the task but there won't be any `async` methods waiting on it.

You could possibly have a "task cache" that is serialized on suspend/resume, and have your `async` methods pull from that cache, invoking other `async` methods only if the task isn't found. I'd say that approach is fraught with pitfalls, though, and totally not worth it.